# Can I connect to external server and change my display page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a webpage where user can log in to an external server. If the login is correct, I want the current display to change to a homepage for the user. After establishing the connection, I want to go to a subpage for example a list page and append information to it. This information will be obtained from the server.

For example from the server page: subdomain.000webhost.com/account/login was used to establish the connection.

The subpage will obtain information from the url:  subdomain.000webhost.com/tables and use JSON to format the print out on the subpage.

Can this whole concept be done? I believe for this setup my current script is not needed. The server is set up fine for the login and table pages. My webpage is able to login to the server. I know how to append the information from the server to my webpage (subpage).

The confusion I am having is how do I go from logging in to an external server and displaying homepage upon successful log in. The changing of page is confusing me. Also concerned if I will lose connection with the server if I do that.

log in page:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="GET" action="http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/">
    <label for="id">Username   </label>
    <input type="text" name="id" id="id" />

    <label for="password">Password   </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>    
</form>

<script>
    //checking if the log in works
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").on("click", function() {
            $.get( "http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/", 
                   $("#form1").serialize(), 
                    function(data) {
                        alert(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Just for simplicity sake, I want to move to the following homepage upon successful connection.

```
<html>
    <div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="e">
        <body><h1>this is homepage</h1></body>
    </div>
</html>
```

Edit:

I have a login page that connects to the external server. As of now, if the credentials are correct, I will receive a message page saying, {"loggedIn":true}, else {"loggedIn":false} when it is incorrect login. Nothing happens beyond this. Thats the problem.

I want to be able to establish this connection and when true, I want to display the homepage. As mentioned earlier, I am asking how to I make this transition from login - server connect - display homepage happen. And if I do that, will I lose connection.

Edit: Omar

```
<div data-role="page" id="loginForm" data-theme="e"><!--Start of Log In Page-->
    <header data-role="header">
        <h1>Log In</h1>       
    </header>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="GET" action="http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/">
        <label for="id">Username   </label>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id" />

        <label for="password">Password   </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>    
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).on("pageinit", "#loginForm", function () {
            $("#submit").on("click", function () {
                $.get("http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/",
                $("#form1").serialize(),
                function (data) {
                    if (data.loggedIn) {
                        $.mobile.changePage("#home");
                    } else {
                        alert("Please try again");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</div><!--End of Log In Page-->

    <div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="e"><!--Start of Home Page-->
        <h1>Budget Planner</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've read this 3 times and it still doesn't make any sense. can you word it any better?

Comment: So let me get this straight.  You want to log a user in to a third party site (possible cross-domain problem), over an unencrypted communication (security problem).  Then based on the result data (which can be tampered with in javascript) give the user some privileges on your site (a potential escalation of privileges problem)?  Does the third party site support OAuth or some other means by which you can perform a 3rd party login in a reasonable manner? Just to clarify, your propose approach is definitely achievable, it just has some significant security problems.

Comment: I am just testing. That server was setup by me. I want to get the connection setup right and work on the security issues later. Unless ofc if I could easily get around the security concerns simultaneously.

Comment: @keshk I don't know why I see so many people say something like "I will work on the security issues later".  The security issues should be a primary consideration when taking on a design such as this.  If you have control over the other both servers, then you have some more options (including implementing OAuth or similar), but truly the security aspect of how you implement this approach is likely to be the #1 driver to your design. It should not be an afterthought.

Comment: @andrew Hi, I updated the explanation. Hope it makes better sense.

Comment: @MikeBrant not procastinating security or anything. It is to be honest  I don't know what exact security issues I should be looking out for thus thought of working on the simple set up first.

Comment: @keshk So why do you feel the need to do this via AJAX to the third party server?  If you kept the web form interacting with a single server and then let that server authenticate against the 3rd server on the end user's behalf, it would simplify the approach greatly.

Comment: I apologize if I am not wording my question properly. There is only one server. To explain the concept further, the user is using his mobile phone which has the app which does this log in to the server(app is written in html/JqueryMobile). When he logs in correctly, I want the app to display the homepage.

Comment: You should not be doing this, period.  There is only one reason to take a username/password to a different site on yours and pass it on, and that is to perform a man in the middle attack to steal someone's password.  Quit hacking dude. Live right.

Comment: at login stage, is jQM framework initialized?

Comment: @Omar Yes JQuery Mobile is initialized at lo gin stage.

Comment: @developerwjk can please advice how I should be doing it then.

Comment: You shouldn't be messing with a third party server's login. Let the user go to the site and login there.

Comment: The idea is to let user login from his mobile app and get updated appended info from the server on his app. Getting him to have to separately go to the site and login defeats the purpose..

Comment: So you want to create a page after successful login?

Comment: I never would have got that from the question.  Why not just make the app show the login page from the server as the first page rather than a login page stored on the device?

Comment: @Omar yes after successful login I want to be moved to the homepage

Comment: @developerwjk Ok I get that part. I will work on that for the security part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is recommended as per the comments above. However, if you want to redirect user within the same jQM page, you should do the following.

Wrap login form in a page `data-role="page"` and give it an id, e.g. `loginForm`.

```
<div data-role="page" id="loginForm">
  <div data-role="content">
    <!-- form elements goes here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Next page

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
  <div data-role="content">
    <!-- dynamic updates -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Then use the below code, place it inside *page div* of `loginForm`. Dont use `.ready()` in jQM.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#loginForm", function () {
    $("#submit").on("click", function () {
        $.get("http://softwarehuttest.x10.mx/public/account/login/",
        $("#form1").serialize(),
        function (data) {
            if (data.loggedIn) {
                $.mobile.changePage("#home");
            } else {
                alert("Please try again");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Note:** Keep in mind that you also need to remove *login* page from both DOM and Navigation history. When back button is hit, user will be redirected to *login* page.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But this is not changing my page to home. It is same as before as in just showing {"loggedIn":true}. I have placeed the updated code in the question for you to see.

Comment: @keshk `loginForm` and `home` pages should be inside the same HTML file. If `home` is located in another HTML file, in `changePage()` instead of `#home` use `URL`, e.g. `$.mobile.changePage("home.html")`

Comment: Hi, Both login and homepages are in the same html file thus your #home is correct.

Comment: @keshk what are you getting on successful login?

Comment: A white page with the text {"loggedIn":true}. This was how it was initially setup to show prior to using your code.

Comment: @keshk I guess you should be using `$.ajax()` not `$.get()`.

Comment: It gives the same results when using $.ajax() .

Comment: Its the function(data) that is not performing the ifelse statements. Even with wrong inputs, the alert message doesn't appear.

Comment: @keshk I'm testing it. yea, i just noticed. I'm entering dummy data.

Comment: @keshk try code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3WxzR/1/) and note changes in form div and code. remove `action` attribute and use `submit` instead of `click`. but change selector to `#form1`.

Comment: It is not working. Right now I no longer see the  text {"loggedIn":true} and at fiddle it fails to load page.

Comment: @keshk I'm sorry, I've tried all possible ways, maybe you need to modify the type of response you get from the server. Other than that, the code above should work fine.

Comment: No prob. Thanks for taking your time to help. :)

Comment: @keshk my pleasure :) i'll remove this. Good luck! Edit: Thanks for accepting my answer, but your problem isn't solved yet.